# Dropdown validation fails in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

My code is like this.
inside model

```
[Required]
    public int ProcedureCategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcedureCategory ProcedureCategory { get; set; }
```

Inside COntroller

```
  ViewBag.ProcedureCategoryList = new SelectList(db.ProcedureCategories.Where(x => !x.IsMainCat),
            "ProcedureCategoryID", "Name");
```

In View (Edit)

```
     @Html.DropDownList("ProcedureCategoryID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ProcedureCategoryList, "--Select Sub Category--", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SubCat" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcedureCategoryID)
```

And this dropdown data is dynamically added by jquery like this

```
 $('#MainCat').change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $('#MainCat').val();
            $.post('@Url.Action("GetSubCategory", "Procedure")', { id: selectedValue }, function (data) {
                $("#SubCat").empty();
                var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' +
                0 + '">' + "--Select Sub Category--" + '</option>';
                $("#SubCat").append(optionhtml1);

                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                data[i].ProcedureCategoryID + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                    $("#SubCat").append(optionhtml);
                });

            });
        });
```

Everything looks okay to me, But the required validation is not happening for this dropdown.Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option you have added in the ajax call has a value of `0` which is a valid integer so it passes validation.

Instead use

```
var select = $("#SubCat");
select.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Select Sub Category--'));
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
  select.append($('<option></option>').val(item.ProcedureCategoryID).text(item.Name));
});
```

which will add the first option with a `null` value.

You should also change the property to nullable `int`

```
[Required]
public int? ProcedureCategoryID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your answer looks correct, but most probably you have missed something in that javascript code for which my dropdown is not populating now :)

Comment: Sorry, I left off the `$(` before `'<option` and missed a closing parenthesis. Now updated